# atOffset utilizando map

Tags: java, map

```
    private OffsetDateTime getDataDistribuicao() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.getPaginaInfoGerais())
            .map(page -> page.<HtmlTableCell>getFirstByXPath(XPATH_CEL_DATA_DISTRIBUICAO))
            .map(HtmlTableCell::getTextContent)
            .map(str -> replaceAndTrim(str))
            .map(str -> getDataDistribuicao(str))
            .map(str -> LocalDateTime.parse( str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN_DATA_HORA)))
            .map(LocalDateTime::atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}
```

No último `map` eu recebo o erro:

> non static method cannot be referenced from a static context

O que fazer?

Comment: atOffset não é método estático, e você está tentando acessá-lo como estático.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito que encontrei foi esse, deu certo:

```
    private OffsetDateTime getDataDistribuicao() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(this.getPaginaInfoGerais())
            .map(page -> page.<HtmlTableCell>getFirstByXPath(XPATH_CEL_DATA_DISTRIBUICAO))
            .map(HtmlTableCell::getTextContent)
            .map(str -> replaceAndTrim(str))
            .map(str -> getDataDistribuicao(str))
            .map(str -> LocalDateTime.parse( str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(PATTERN_DATA_HORA)).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC))
            .orElse(null);
}
```